# Is the quotient of a holomorphic group action a complex manifold?

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry, manifolds, complex-geometry, group-actions

Let $M$ be a complex manifold on which the group $G$ acts properly  and holomorphic. Is $M/G$ then a complex manifold?

> **My attempt:**
>
> We need charts for $M/G$. For any $m \in M$ we take $U\subset M$
>   small enough such that the restriction of the quotient map $q$ is a
>   homeomorphism. (**Is this possible because of proper discontinuity?**)
>   We have a chart $\phi_U: U \to \mathbb C^n$. As $q|_U$ is a
>   homeomorphism, this gives us a chart $\phi_U \circ (q|_U)^{-1}:
>  q(U)\to \mathbb C^n$.
>
> We need to check that the functions $[\phi_V \circ (q|_V)^{-1}] \circ
>  [\phi_U \circ (q|_U)^{-1}]^{-1}: \mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n$ are
>   holomorphic. But this is the case if $(q|_U)^{-1} \circ (q|_U)$ is
>   holomorphic. But this is simply the translation by a group element
>   which is holomorphic as  we assumed the group action to be
>   holomorphic.

Is this right and is this enough?

Edit: Actually I want $G$ to also be discrete and act freely.

Answer (score 1):

You’re right but the idea is more general.

When your action is properly discontinuous you get that $\pi: M\to M/G$ is a covering map that is open so you can define the local charts in your natural way and you get that $M/G$ is a local Euclidean complex space;

In general $M/G$ is not an Hausdorff space;

$M/G$ will be second countable because $\pi$ is surjective and open and $X$ is second countable;

It is possible built an olomorphic structure on $M/G$? I think that it is a really difficult question because in general your composition

$q|_V^{-1}\circ q|_U$ is not simply a moltiplication with respect a fixed $g\in G$

Comment: I see, I forgot some assumptions. I had in mind that $G$ is discrete and also acts freely. So we can apply the quotient manifold theorem.  
What really interests me is the complex structure. Why should $q|_V^{-1} \circ q|_U$ not be multiplication with some $g$?